# Where is the list of backed-up files within the Samsung smart switch backup folder?

Tags: backup

I backed up my Galaxy phone using smart switch. I backed it up to my local drive.  I would like to view a list of all of the phone's files that were backed up.  I would prefer to do this just using Windows or Linux without needing to connect a phone. Is there a manifest file with this information?

Comment: Nope. Why do you want that?

Comment: Default save locations: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00048603/